# Connection refused for apache atlas server

Tags: amazon-ec2, solr, hbase, apache-atlas

I have setup apache atlas on EC2. After setup , I started the apache atlas using command python2 atlas_start.py and it successfully started with below log:

```
configured for local hbase.
hbase started.
configured for local solr.
solr started.
setting up solr collections...
starting atlas on host localhost
starting atlas on port 21000
..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Apache Atlas Server started!!!
```

However, when I try to hit the Server URL to verify if apache atlas is up and running. It gave me connection refused error. Below is the command I used to hit the server:
  curl -u username:password http://localhost:21000/api/atlas/admin/version

Also, while setup it didnt ask me for username and password SO, I am using admin:admin as username password.

Comment: `netstat -a` should be able to tell you if something is listening on port 21000 at all.

Comment: Would you please see the answer I have posted? I have explained the issue completely! Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There would be many reasons - do the following checks

1. Please check the logs which would be in the `logs` directory based on how you have it setup. (if you just ran it through mvn)
2. You need hbase(atleast) and solr/elastic/cassandra (atlas backends). Check if you are running embedded mode - where atlas will start its own backend. It is usually set as an environment variable. ie: `MANAGE_LOCAL_HBASE`
3. Make sure `atlas-application.properties` have the right configurations before you start it.

   Hope this helps!

EDIT:
I noticed you mentioned ec2. Make sure you have configured the right security groups.

Answer (score 0):

you have to build the server using "mvn clean install -Pdist,", once this is done you need to navigate to the distro/target/ folder and then run the atlas_start.py from there.

Here solution

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Apache-Atlas-Started-but-with-Errors-and-Warnings/td-p/134183

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this script is that starting atlas using `atlas_start.py` takes about 10 minutes. While its process is not completed, you face to `connection refused` error.

In order to see whether it is completed or not, you can check the `application.log` file in `logs` directory using `tail -n 10 application.log` or `cat application.log`. In *2.1.0* version the last 10 line of application.log is as follows:

```
2021-03-28 06:00:06,536 INFO  - [main:] ~ Starting service org.apache.atlas.web.service.ActiveInstanceElectorService (Services:68)
2021-03-28 06:00:06,540 INFO  - [NotificationHookConsumer thread-0:] ~ [atlas-hook-consumer-thread]: Starting (Logging$class:66)
2021-03-28 06:00:06,542 INFO  - [main:] ~ HA is not enabled, no need to start leader election service (ActiveInstanceElectorService:103)
2021-03-28 06:00:06,542 INFO  - [NotificationHookConsumer thread-0:] ~ ==> HookConsumer doWork() (NotificationHookConsumer$HookConsumer:530)
2021-03-28 06:00:06,544 INFO  - [NotificationHookConsumer thread-0:] ~ Atlas Server is ready, can start reading Kafka events. (NotificationHookConsumer$HookConsumer:936)
2021-03-28 06:00:06,628 WARN  - [NotificationHookConsumer thread-0:] ~ [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=atlas] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {ATLAS_HOOK=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater:968)
2021-03-28 06:00:06,757 WARN  - [NotificationHookConsumer thread-0:] ~ [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=atlas] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 4 : {ATLAS_HOOK=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater:968)
2021-03-28 06:00:06,932 WARN  - [NotificationHookConsumer thread-0:] ~ [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=atlas] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 6 : {ATLAS_HOOK=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater:968)
2021-03-28 06:00:07,585 INFO  - [main:] ~ AuditFilter initialization started (AuditFilter:64)
2021-03-28 06:00:07,585 INFO  - [main:] ~ REST_API_ENABLE_DELETE_TYPE_OVERRIDE=false (AuditFilter:69)
```

After that you can see the login page `http://localhost:21000`:
[image: apache atlas login page]

or using curl command:

```
~ ➤ curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:21000/api/atlas/admin/version         

{"Description":"Metadata Management and Data Governance Platform over Hadoop","Revision":"release","Version":"2.1.0","Name":"apache-atlas"}%   
default username and password are **admin**.
```